# setInterval/setTimeout check value of variables

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm writing some javascript which relies on a few asynchronous method calls,

```
var one = asyncCall();
var two = differentAsyncCall();
```

I understand that I can work with either of their return values like so

```
var one = asyncCall(function(results){
  //do stuff
});
var two = differentAsyncCall(function(results){
//do more
});
```

I would like to perform operations with both of them, so to do that, both async calls must be completed. I know that I can do something like:

```
asyncCall(function(results){

  var firstReturn = results;

  differentAsyncCall(function(results2){
    var secondReturn = results2;
    //do stuff now that they're both defined.
  });   

});
```

I'm curious if there's a way to use setInterval or setTimeout to do something like:

```
var one = asyncCall(function(results){
  return results;
});
var two = differentAsyncCall(function(results){
  return results;
});

window.setInterval(function(){
  if( one && two){
    //do stuff now that they're defined
    //remove the timer
  }
},250);
```

Comment: Using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to beat asynchronous calls, will not be reliable.

Comment: I highly recommend the wonderful async library for things like this. https://github.com/caolan/async In particular, the async.parallel method.

Comment: Does your `asyncCall()` function actually return a value? Your example with the timer/interval has `return results` in the callback function, but does `asyncCall()` do anything with that return value?

Comment: @thefourtheye could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent use case for using Promises/Deferreds, but that is another concept and needs to include a library (at least for now).

As you're using pure javascript (no library), you could add this simple helper method somewhere:

```
    function whenAll(promises, doneProperty, callback){
        promises[doneProperty] = true;
        for(var key in promises)
            if(promises[key] == false) return false;            
        if(callback) callback();
        return true;
    }
```

(The following example contains 3 async calls that need to be completed)

Then you'd do:

```
//This object contains all the async calls needed to be completed, key is the name
var promises = {"asyncCall1": false, "asyncCall2": false, "asyncCall3": false};

//And the magic comes here:
var results1, results2, results3;  //These will contain the results
(function(whenAllCallback){
    asyncCall1(function(results){
      results1 = results;
      whenAll(promises, "asyncCall1", whenAllCallback);
    });
    asyncCall2(function(results){
      results2 = results;
      whenAll(promises, "asyncCall2", whenAllCallback);
    });
    asyncCall3(function(results){
      results3 = results;
      whenAll(promises, "asyncCall3", whenAllCallback);
    });    
})(function(){
    //This executes when all calls have been completed
    alert(results1);
    alert(results2);
    alert(results3);
});
```

Note that the 3 async calls can end in any order, and the callback will be executed when all are finished, as desired.

This syntax may be difficult at the beginning, but once you get used to it, it becomes easy. Before entering to real promises, you can use this code.

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 4):

This is a concept called Promises that can be used here. Promises are a part of deferred Object concept.

The idea is to assign the async calls to two variables. When both the variables are available, then take some action, which is what you are trying to do.

I have used the jQuery version, the documentation for which can be found here.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

It is quite easy to follow. I am not sure how to implement this in pure Javascript. You would be better off using any async library

Answer (score 0):

Another version of my previous answer, this accepts return values as parameters in the final callback, and uses a promises array instead of object (simpler):

```
function whenAll(promisesKeys, doneProperty, callback, returnValue){
    var returnValues = promisesKeys.returnValues = promisesKeys.returnValues || new Array(promisesKeys.length);
    returnValues[promisesKeys.indexOf(doneProperty)] = (returnValue === undefined ? null : returnValue);
    for(var i=0; i < returnValues.length; i++)
        if(returnValues[i] === undefined) return false;
    delete promisesKeys.returnValues;
    callback.apply(this, returnValues);
    return true;
}
```

This is a sample usage:

```
//This array contains all the async calls keys needed to be completed
var promisesKeys = ["call1", "call2", "call3"];

//And the magic comes here:
(function(whenAllCallback){
    //Intentionally call the methods in different order
    asyncCall2(function(results){
      whenAll(promisesKeys, "call2", whenAllCallback, results);
    });
    asyncCall1(function(results){
      whenAll(promisesKeys, "call1", whenAllCallback, results);
    });
    asyncCall3(function(results){
      whenAll(promisesKeys, "call3", whenAllCallback, results);
    });    
})(function(results1, results2, results3){   //These come in the same order as in the initial array
    //This executes when all calls have been completed
    console.log("ALL FINISHED:!");
    console.log(results1);
    console.log(results2);
    console.log(results3);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/B3x72/

Cheers